# Navigation Menu Hover Effect only on a Particular Occasion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I need the exact effect of this website's navigation menu http://recruitmentmalta.com/ptowers/ but in neater code. This code was generated with a tool which converts from PSD to HTML/CSS and basically created a bunch of useless code. I know how to make that menu, except for the part where the Shop Now effect should turn off only if the contact is hovered over.

Any ideas of how I can recreate that hovering off effect when I hover over the contact button (when Shop Now gets turned off)?

This is what I have done so far to give you an idea

```
    <ul>
        <li id="homeButton"> <img src="images/home.png" onmouseout="this.src='images/home.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/homeHover.png'" width="115" height="55" alt="home" /></li>
        <li id="aboutButton"> <img src="images/about.png" onmouseout="this.src='images/about.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/aboutHover.png'" width="115" height="55" alt="about" /></li>
        <li id="newsButton"> <img src="images/news.png" onmouseout="this.src='images/news.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/newsHover.png'" width="115" height="55" alt="news" /></li>
        <li id="brandsButton"> <img src="images/brands.png" onmouseout="this.src='images/brands.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/brandsHover.png'" width="115" height="55" alt="brands" /></li>
        <li id="storesButton"> <img src="images/stores.png" onmouseout="this.src='images/stores.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/storesHover.png'" width="115" height="55" alt="stores" /></li>
        <li id="careersButton"> <img src="images/careers.png" onmouseout="this.src='images/careers.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/careersHover.png'" width="115" height="55" alt="careers" /></li>
        <li id="contactButtonMenu"> <img src="images/contactButton.png" onmouseout="this.src='images/contactButton.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/contactButtonHover.png'"  width="115" height="55" alt="contact" /></li>
        <li id="shopNowButton"> <img src="images/shopNowHover.png" width="114" height="53" alt="Shop Now" /> </li>
    </ul>
```

This is my JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/GHHJM/

Comment: Please post the code sample in question so that the question is more concise.

Comment: @John Strickler - I gave the website in concern, therefore the code is all there, other than that I only have a sketch of the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved this in a rather efficient easy way, this is the code part for just the effect of two buttons. I hope this will be of help if any body needs it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Hover</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>

<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contactButton").hover(function() {
        $(contactButtonMenu).attr("src","images/contactButtonHover.png");
            }, function() {
        $(contactButtonMenu).attr("src","images/contactButton.png");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contactButton").hover(function() {
        $(shopNowButton).attr("src","images/shopNow.png");
            }, function() {
        $(shopNowButton).attr("src","images/shopNowHover.png");
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<img id="contactButtonMenu" src="images/contactButton.png" alt"Contact Button" class="contactButton" />
<img id="shopNowButton" src="images/shopNowHover.png" alt="Shop Now" class="shopNowButton" />

</body>
</html>
```

However this is not working in Firefox, any ideas?

Comment: @bpeterson76 thanks for your help mate, but with jQuery it turned out to be much simpler

Answer (score 1):

That's not so difficult.

Build the menu in a `<ul>` element as is so common today.  Build a style called hover with a border on it to mimic the highlight.  Set the last element's default class (style when the page is rendered) to have the border.  All else are just normal for starters.  Remember, when dealing with styles you can "stack" classes such as:

```
<element class="firstclass hover otherclass">
```

Now, build a hover action:
`$("li").hover(function () {
    $(elementtoputborderon).addClass("hover");
 },
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  })`

And, for the part where it turns off:
`$("#idofcontactbtn").hover(function () {
    $('#idoflastelement').removeClass("hover");
 },
function () {
    $('#idoflastelement').addClass("hover");
  })`

To get the "fade" effect on the last element, you could try something like this:

`$('#lastitem').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pretty-hover', 500);
  });`

Comment: I'm new to javascript, so I'm not familiar with this jargon. When you refer to style you mean create a class, right? should each li have an element?

Comment: I added all the hovering stuff needed in the code which I posted above, should I only add the element thing I for the contact button?

Comment: I added a JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/GHHJM/ - let me know what I am doing wrong. The .hover class is in the end of the css too.